# Design Automation API debugging export to IFC throws several erros

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

[Attached image showing error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jsjpx.png)

Hi, I am testing a sample code locally to export IFC using Design Automation for Revit
https://github.com/yiskang/aps-revit-ifc-exporter-appbundle

I get errors saying
1)Exception thrown at 0x00007FF815106453 (RevitDB.dll) in Revit.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.

2)Exception thrown at 0x00007FF90CA04B2C (KernelBase.dll) in Revit.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.

what probably is causing this and how do I solve.
Any assistance is appreciated.

I tried to debug locally, the sample code provided in github repo. I am expecting successful ifc export using Design Automation API for revit.

Comment: Does this happen with only API code? Or does is crash when you try to export with UI as well? How many files are affected?

You might want to get in touch with `forge[dot]help[at]autodesk.com` and file a support case.

Comment: When running the addin locally, it actually doesn't run on DA. The addin runs on Revit Desktop. This is my first time to see this error message. I'm happy to help you resolve this issue. Could you share more details on how to reproduce this issue? A simple visual studio project would be very helpful for investigation.

Comment: @EasonKang
Ok Let me explain the case in detail, when I posted this question I didnt know about following, that this error is occuring on the specific laptop. Plugin works fine on my other laptop. Both the laptop I tested has same revit version. 

I am using the Repo that basically you yourself have developed for IFC export using DA. I have not modified code.  Errors are thrown on the specific laptop only, It worked fine on the other laptop when I tested.

Comment: @omkarbhagwat Could you try to replace the DLL dependencies shipped with Revit in the C# project with the ones and re-compile the plugin with Visual Studio on your laptops? The pre-complied plugin DLLs were complied with Revit 2022.0.1. The DLLs should be replaced are `NewtonSoft.Json.dll`, `Revit.IFC.Common.dll`, `RevitAPI.dll` and `RevitAPIIFC.dll`. In addition, upgrade `DesignAutomationBridge` version to your Revit version.

Comment: If this doesn't work, could you try to check if any error message shows up in the [Revit Journal](https://www.autodesk.com/support/technical/article/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/Location-of-journal-files.html) for this plugin?

Comment: @EasonKang
Thanks for the support. It was not the problem in code or .dlls rather the revit file I was trying to export to ifc. I was not able to export the file from UI either. 
Using the same DA code and other revit files, I tried exporting to IFCs, it worked fine.
 Thanks again!

Comment: @RahulBhobe, Yes, Revit crashes when exporting from UI as well.  will get it touch with support. Thanks!

Comment: @omkarbhagwat If Revit crashes when exporting from UI as well, while contacting our product support, could you try to update Revit IFC Addin on the laptops encountering this problem to see if it helps? You can download the Revit IFC addin via [Autodesk App Store](https://apps.autodesk.com/All/en/List/Search?isAppSearch=True&searchboxstore=All&facet=&collection=&sort=&query=IFC) or [Revit IFC GitHub](https://github.com/Autodesk/revit-ifc/releases).